# Developing an Offline Native Application from a Web Dev background

Tags: desktop-application

I am planning to create a simple bookkeeping software that needs to run offline. Thing is, I came from a Web developing background and I can easily write it if that is the case (MySQL database and php...)

I know this question might be teetering to the verge of subjectivism (no such word!), but can anyone help me make the transition from web based to desktop? Like what language would you recommend? What IDE could I use? Replacement for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use your existing Web application developing skills and create a browser based desktop application using *server* and *MySQL* that are running locally. 

[**Advantage:** You can start right away]

**Option 2:**

Develop a desktop application, using these:

*(There are many choices apart from what I am suggesting)*

IDE: *Eclipse*

Language: *Java*

RDBMS/Backend: *MySQL*

Hope this helps

Comment: I also thought about doing what you suggested in option 1. Thanks. And yes, it does Help :)